# Always reload model when entering a route

Tags: ember.js

I have a route with a simple route handler that implements the `model()` hook.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.queryRecord('some-model', {});
  }
});
```

I allow the user to transition to this route by clicking a `link-to`.

How can I force ember re-query for the record from my backend every time the user enters this route? (And not just the first time the user loads this particular route)

I am using Ember 2.8.3 and Ember-Data 2.10.0.

Comment: How are you calling link-to helper ? are you providing model to link-to helper ? [read this](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/templates/links/#toc_example-for-multiple-segments)

Comment: You can look at the route's [`refresh`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh) method or the model's [`reload`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload)

Comment: @kumkanillam - I am not providing the model to the link-to - I am calling it like: `{{#link-to 'our-route'}}Some Label{{/link-to}}`

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony - What is easiest way to call refresh? Is there some lifestyle hook where I can call it? I am frankly surprised there is no easy configurable way to always opt in to a refresh each time the route is entered.

Comment: then it will always execute the model hook, you don't need to force ember to re-query using refresh

Comment: @kumkanillam - that is not the behavior I am seeing. If I put a breakpoint / `console.log('something')` within the model hook it's clear that `model()` is only being called once, despite not passing the model.

Comment: That means you need to provide your exact code/scenario here to understand better. please have a look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/0c09731f56b23b2095e57acfc2372473?openFiles=templates.two.hbs%2C&route=%2Fone) when ever `one` route enters you can see model hook is being called..

Comment: @OrenHizkiya from what route to what route are you transitioning? It sounds like this route is a parent route and you're transitioning between child routes. That would mean the parent is always active, so the hook isn't called.

Comment: In your case you're trying to get single record but without any params (so which record should be loaded?), that's kinda strange. If you would like to load specific single record by query params, declare these params for route, get it by `model(params)` and use it in queryParams. For example `queryRecord('model', { name: params.name })`. If you would like to force load specific record by id, use `findRecord('model', params.id, { reload: true });`. If you would like to force load all records for model, use: `findAll('model', { reload: true });`.

Comment: @KarolŁuckiewicz - Understood that this is a bit of an odd situation but without going into details, the unfortunate reality is that the structure and querying need to be the way they are.

Comment: @locks - You are correct that I am navigating from a child route. Seems obvious in retrospect, but I needed the new set of eyes. Any suggestions on how to force the parent route to re-query its model when transitioning from a child?

Comment: Thanks all for the help. I have worked out the issue. Will post an update with more information later which will hopefully be helpful to others.

Comment: @OrenHizkiya Any update? Ha

Comment: @JoshuaF.Rountree - sorry mate, it's been way too long for me to remember exactly what the issue was. Probably some bone-headed thinking on my end.